# How to convert a Task into a Task<T>?

Tags: c#, task

I'm sure this has been asked before but I can't seem to phrase the question right to get any answers that solve my question.

I've got a base class that implements an interface with a Save method that returns a Task:

```
public interface ICanSave
{
    Task Save();
}

public class Base : ICanSave
{
    public Task Save()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Of course the Save method will actually do something, like saving to a database, which is why it's a Task, so it can be awaited. If I have a Foo class that inherits from the base class:

```
public class Foo : Base { }
```

Currently, you'd have to do the instantiation and save in two distinct steps:

```
var foo = new Foo();

await foo.Save();
```

However I'd like to be able to do the instantiation and the save as an expression and return a Task also. I've come up with this helper:

```
public static class Helper<T> where T : ICanSave
{
    public static Task<T> Save(T obj)
    {
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
        {
            obj.Save();
            source.SetResult(obj);
        });

        return source.Task;
    }
}
```

Which could then be used to do:

```
var foo = await Helper<Foo>.Save(new Foo());
```

Which is more like the result I'm trying to achieve, but it seems pretty cumbersome, plus the helper seems to be pushing the Save to a Task twice (once for the original Task and a second time in the helper).

Is there a more simple way to do this conversion from a Task to a Task of T?

Comment: On a side note,checkout `Task.Run` which will be more suitable in theese cases than `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but from what I've read, Task.Run uses ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem under the hood.

Comment: Yes but it provides a generic version which would solve your initial problem.
`How to convert a Task into a Task<T>?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see a point of such helper method, but if you really want you can like this:

```
public static class Helper<T> where T : ICanSave {
    public static async Task<T> Save(T obj) {
        await obj.Save();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Evk, I originally chose @Enigmativity's answer because a) he managed to do it all in one line which follows the functional programming style that I'm trying to develop and b) because his method returned just a Task of T rather than an async Task of T, however after testing your solution in my project, it works just as well and considering your comment about losing exceptions, I've accepted your answer.

Comment: @Aaron there is no such thing as "async Task". `async` keyword makes compiler to rewrite your method in a certain way, but it still returns `Task<T>`, just as any other method without `async` keyword. Also, forcing doing things in one line with no apparent reason will not lead to anything good (and not necessary will result in "functional style").